# Xcode 4 disable snapshots creation on refactoring

Tags: xcode4

I turned on Xcode4's snapshot on replace feature.  I want to turn it off.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`File->Project Settings` (or `File->Workspace Settings` if you're in a Workspace), and then click on the 'Snapshots' tab: you want to uncheck the "Create snapshot of project before mass-editing operations" box.

Thanks to [Teknogrebo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524147/teknogrebo) for pointing out in the comments how to do this for workspaces rather than projects.

Comment: Just to save other people the few minutes confusion that I had, it's under File->Workspace Settings if you are working within a Workspace. (Obvious really).

Comment: @lxt, could you add "... or File->Workspace Settings, if you have a workspace", to your answer? (It will be more visible than in these comments.)

Comment: How to get the prompt back after you said "don't show again"?